# Cannot save empty array to database when serialized

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, serialization

In Ruby on Rails, a model with a serialized array field will not update on `.save()` if the array is empty, where it previously had data.

I'm using:

- Ruby 2.2.1
- Rails 4.2.1
- sqlite3 1.3.10

  I created a new model with a field set as text:

  rails g model User name:string example:text

In the User.rb file I added:

```
serialize :example, Array
```

I instantiated a new instance of the User class:

```
test = User.new
<User id: nil, name: nil, example: [], created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

Then I save the user to make sure it saves correctly:

```
test.save()
(0.1ms)  begin transaction
SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?)  [["created_at", "2015-05-27 16:17:31.902342"], ["updated_at", "2015-05-27 16:17:31.902342"]]
(0.7ms)  commit transaction
=> true
```

And added some data in so that it feels happy and purposeful:

```
test.example.push(1)
test.example.push(2)
```

And save it up:

```
test.save()
(0.1ms)  begin transaction
SQL (0.3ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "example" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "users"."id" = ?  [["example", "---\n- 1\n- 2\n"], ["updated_at", "2015-05-27 16:17:50.331777"], ["id", 1]]
(0.8ms)  commit transaction
=> true
```

And made sure everything saved nicely:

```
test
<User id: 1, name: nil, example: [1, 2], created_at: "2015-05-27 16:17:31", updated_at: "2015-05-27 16:17:50">
```

I deleted one item, verified it has been deleted, and saved it, making sure the SQL output shows the UPDATE:

```
test.example.delete(1)
 => 1
test
<User id: 1, name: nil, example: [2], created_at: "2015-05-27      16:17:31", updated_at: "2015-05-27 16:17:50">
test.save()
(0.1ms)  begin transaction
SQL (0.9ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "example" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "users"."id" = ?  [["example", "---\n- 2\n"], ["updated_at", "2015-05-27 16:18:30.148553"], ["id", 1]]
(8.9ms)  commit transaction
=> true
```

I deleted the last piece of data from array, verified empty array, and saved it. Note the lack of an UPDATE action and that it returns true:

```
test.example.delete(2)
=> 2
test
<User id: 1, name: nil, example: [], created_at: "2015-05-27 16:17:31", updated_at: "2015-05-27 16:18:30">
test.save()
(0.1ms)  begin transaction
(0.1ms)  commit transaction
=> true
```

Multiple saves get the same result. A new User object still has that last piece of data in it:

```
test = User.find(1)
User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
<User id: 1, name: nil, example: [2], created_at: "2015-05-27 16:17:31", updated_at: "2015-05-27 16:18:30">
```

A workaround is removing the "Array" from the serialize line in the model initializes the field as nil. But this means the first time I add data to a new instance I have to set the field manually to an empty array (`test.example = []`) in order to call `.push()` on it. Everything works fine in this setup, and the newly emptied array saves happily to the DB.

I saw a closed issue on the Rails Github indicating that serialized columns should always be saved, but have no idea if this is pertinent:

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/8328

I could not discern anything from the serialize source code that could illuminate me:

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Serializers/Xml/Serializer/serialize

Why does adding "Array" at the end of the serialize line cause empty arrays to not be saved to the database?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Here are some tips for writing a question: Don't tack on "Ruby on Rails" or similar tags. Stack Overflow (and search engines) use the tags you've defined for the question. Instead simply write a short descriptive sentence. In the body, it's not necessary to use headings. Instead, write normally, as you would when writing to a co-worker. Stack Overflow is somewhat like an encyclopedia of programming Q&A but with a less formal style. Emulate the style of other questions to maintain the common look and feel. Also learn inline code formatting.

Comment: Thanks for the advice and for the edit! I will keep this advice in mind for future inquiries. 

Can you elaborate on the inline code formatting? I was using console output for my post because I thought it best showcased the issue.

Answer (score 1):

SQLite does not support an Array column type. I think what's happening is when you try to save the User with an empty array for the example attribute, it's being interpreted as no change to the example column. What happens if you try this after you create your test user with example data?

```
test.example = nil
test.save
```

Alternatively, what happens with this?

```
test.example = [nil]
test.save
```

It seems like the solution would be to use an [ActiveRecord callback](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html) such as `before_save` to check the user model's example attribute to determine if it is an empty array. If so, set the attribute to `nil` or `[nil]` (whichever works) and then the data should persist accordingly.

Comment: Setting and saving as just nil works as long as it does not try to save the blank array first.

The [nil] solution saves as well, but leaves any .length calls returning 1 which is non-optimal.

My main hope here is to figure out why adding Array to the serialize line illicits different behavior on a blank save than if it is not there.

My current workaround is to just use Serialize on its own, sans Array and then check for 'nil' when the create method is called:


`test.example = [ ] if !test.example`